# Trying to install golang on a Solaris 11.3 VM

Tags: solaris, package-management

I was trying to install Go (golang) on a newly minted Solaris 11.3 VM (downloaded from Oracle), but I was getting the following error:

```
root@solaris:/export/home/jdeppe# pkg install golang-15
Creating Plan (Running solver): /
pkg install: No matching version of developer/golang-15 can be installed:
  Reject:  pkg://solaris/developer/golang-15@1.5-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
  Reason:  No version matching 'require' dependency runtime/perl-520@5.20.1,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.90.0 can be installed
    ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-520@5.20.1-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
    Reason:  No version matching 'optional' dependency runtime/perl-512@5.12.5,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.69.0 can be installed
      ----------------------------------------
      Reject:  pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-512@5.12.5-5.12.0.0.0.90.0
               pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-512@5.12.5-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
      Reason:  This version is excluded by installed incorporation consolidation/userland/userland-incorporation@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.3.0
      ----------------------------------------
    Reject:  pkg://solaris/runtime/perl-520@5.20.1-5.12.0.0.0.95.0
    Reason:  No version matching 'optional' dependency runtime/perl-512@5.12.5,5.11-5.12.0.0.0.69.0 can be installed
    ----------------------------------------
```

After some googling I finally ran: `pkg change-facet facet.version-lock.runtime/perl-512=false`, after which I was able to install golang-15. Sweet!!

Can someone explain what I just did :). I know this question sounds weird, but I managed to solve it as I was writing it (I hadn't figured out the `change-facet` stuff). I'd still like to understand the implications of this action.

Could (should) I have solved this differently?

Answer (score 5):

The current version of the `developer/golang-15` package has a dependency on Perl 5.22:

```
$ pkg contents -r -o fmri,type -t depend developer/golang-15
FMRI                                         TYPE
pkg:/runtime/perl-522@5.22.1-5.12.0.0.0.95.0 require
pkg:/system/library@0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.3.0   require
release/evaluation                           require
```

In your case it apparently was still dependent on Perl 5.20. Either way, the trouble is that the default Solaris 11.3 installation comes with Perl 5.12. Since other packages have a dependency on the Perl runtime as well, the system tries to lock in this version to prevent broken packages. This is done through a Solaris package management feature called *Incorporations*. The incorporation package serves to prevent unintended upgrades or downgrades of OS packages. However, for certain packages it will provide a loop hole so the administrator can install a different version. By setting `facet.version-lock.runtime/perl-512=false` you effectively told Solaris to release the lock on Perl 5.12, and allow an upgrade to a later version. Subsequent to the Golang install, your default Perl version will change from 5.12 to 5.22:

```
$ perl --version

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 1 (v5.22.1) built for i86pc-solaris-thread-multi-64

Copyright 1987-2015, Larry Wall
```

Here is a link to the Oracle documentation that explains this feature in more detail: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28984/gmias.html